# Installed Module. Getting "Cannot find module" error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have installed a package called 'munch' on Windows 10 from https://github.com/ccampbell/html-muncher

However I am not able to execute a command. When I say on the command line

```
munch --help
```

This is the error I get

[image]

I checked out AppData and found that munch was installed at:

[image]

[image]

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, It's a little unclear given what you've said. My inclination is that munch is not where is should be. I'm guessing that because the error says it should be within your node_modules folder, but it's outside. Other than that, I'm not sure, please provide some more screen caps of the contents of the node_modules folder and all relevant sub-folders